# SqlAlchemy query and filter by number of relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So currently I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` where

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    ...
    bars = db.relationship('Bar', backref='foo', lazy='dynamic')
    ...
```

Here, a `Foo` can have many `Bar`'s.
How can I query `Foo` such that I can filter by the number of `Bar`'s? Something like `Foo.query.filter(Foo.bars.count() == x).first()`

Would there be another way to do this other than keeping a count variable?

Comment: Are you asking to get the first X results from a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: I'm trying to only get the `Foo`'s with exactly x `Bar`'s, I guess in the example I gave, the `first()` doesn't really matter

Comment: It's best to just use python code to do it. Query all your Foos and then keep the ones who has `len(foo.bars) == X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL query would be one way of doing it (assuming x = 2):

```sql
SELECT parent.id, COUNT(child.tid) AS num_bars 
  FROM parent 
  JOIN child ON parent.id = child.tid 
  GROUP BY parent.id 
  HAVING COUNT(child.tid) = 2;
```

This would translate to (sqlalchemy):

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

x = 2
q = (session.query(Foo, sa.func.count(Bar.foo_id).label('num_bars'))
            .join(Bar)
            .group_by(Foo.id)
            .having(sa.literal_column('num_bars') == x)
            .from_self(Foo))
```

the flask-sqlalchemy equivalent would probably be

```py
q = (db.session.query(Foo, sa.func.count(Bar.foo_id).label('num_bars'))
              .join(Bar)
              .group_by(Foo.id)
              .having(sa.literal_column('num_bars') >= x)
              .from_self(Foo))
```

Another way to do it would be to use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT parent.id 
FROM parent 
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
         FROM child 
           WHERE child.tid = parent.id
  ) = 2
```

which would look like this using SQLAlchemy:

```py
subq = (session.query(sa.func.count(Bar.foo_id))
               .filter(Bar.foo_id == Foo.id)
               .scalar_subquery())
q = session.query(Foo).filter(subq == 2)
```

Comment: thank you! Would there be a way to only count particular `Bar`'s? For example, only counting the number of `Bar`'s who's field `Bar.x>1`?

Comment: You would add a filter like `filter(Bar.x > 1)` to the query (or subquery, in the second example)